# Как добавлять в базу MySQL не сами blob-файлы, а ссылки на них, а потом по ссылкам выводить картинки?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, вывод

уважаемые эксперты! Несмотря на обилие информации примерно об этом, не нашел конкретного руководства: как делать то, о чем говорю в заголовке. Ниже прилагаю код, как загружаю сами BLOB-файлы в базу. Как я понял, это не очень эффективно. А как выгружать картинки на "фронт" по ссылкам в базе?

```
 <?php

    $sqlserver = "localhost";
    $sqluser = "root";
    $sqlpass = "";
    $sqlbase = "lk";
 
$connection = mysqli_connect($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlbase);

    if (!$connection) {
        echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL<br>";
        echo "<br>Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        echo "<br>Текст ошибки error:" . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit;
    }

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name']));
$but = $_POST['commoditycard'];
$query = "INSERT INTO pl (id,img,discript) VALUES('','$image','$but')";  
$qry = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    ?>
```

Comment: Сохраняйте изображения в директорию, а в БД пишите полный путь до файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sqlserver = "localhost";
$sqluser = "root";
$sqlpass = "";
$sqlbase = "lk";
 
$connection = mysqli_connect($sqlserver, $sqluser, $sqlpass, $sqlbase);

if (!$connection) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL<br>";
    echo "<br>Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    echo "<br>Текст ошибки error:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}

$fileName = md5($_FILES['myimage']['name'] . rand());

if (!is_dir('images')) {
    mkdir('images');
}

rename($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $fileName . '.jpg');

$but = $_POST['commoditycard'];
$query = "INSERT INTO pl (id,img,discript) VALUES('','$fileName','$but')";  
$qry = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```